# Change color of specific text in React Native

Tags: css, react-native

I am making an automatic search bar using Textinput and Flatlist. I want to change the color of the word entered in Textinput when it is listed in Flatlist.

```
<View style={styles.giftModalTextInput}>
            <TextInput
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoCorrect={false}
              clearButtonMode="always"
              onChangeText={onChangeNicknane}
              placeholderTextColor={'#929292'}
              style={styles.textInput}
              placeholder="search nickname"
              value={keyword}
            />
          </View>
          <FlatList
            style={{... style...}}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            data={keyItems}
            disableScrollViewPanResponder={true}
            renderItem={({item, index}: {item: any; index: any}) => {
              return (
                <Pressable
                  style={{ ... styles...}}
                  onPress={() => {
                    setKeyword(item.nickname); // select item
                    Keyboard.dismiss() // hide keyboard
                  }}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 16, color: '#fff', paddingLeft: 10}}>
                    {item.nickname} // here!!!
                  </Text>
                </Pressable>
              );
            }}
          />
        </View>
```

[image]

Any good way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you !

```
  const replaceStringWithJSX = (str, find, replace) => {
    const parts = str.split(find);
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
      result.push(parts[i]);
      if (i < parts.length - 1) result.push(replace);
    }
    return result;
  }
  
  renderItem={({item, index}: {item: any; index: any}) => {
    return (
      <Pressable
        style={{ ... styles...}}
        onPress={() => {
          setKeyword(item.nickname); // select item
          Keyboard.dismiss() // hide keyboard
        }}>
        {renderText(item.nickname)}
      </Pressable>
    );
  }}
  
  const renderText = (nickname: string) => {
    return (
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: '#000', paddingLeft: 10 }}>
        {replaceStringWithJSX(
          nickname,
          keyword,
          <Text style={{ color: 'yellow' }}>{keyword}</Text>
        )}
      </Text>
    );
  };
```